# Should <head> and <body> tags be on a different level of indentation to <html>?

Tags: html, tags, indentation

I have always wondered but can't really find an answer anywhere if there are any set standards regarding indenting the body or head tag.

*Is this version correct?*

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

*Or this one?*

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whilst I appreciate that it probably doesn't make the slightest bit of difference as far as the functionality of the final website goes, we are all human beings, and all blessed with the gift / burden that is curiosity.

Are there any set standards or does it not matter?

Comment: *"or does it not matter?"* : It does not matter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HTML does not care about indentation, it only requires proper nesting. It is parsed the same (except for whitespace text nodes of course), it does really not matter for correctness.

While proper indentation does matter for readability, many people choose not to indent `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags as their structure is trivial, and only shifts the whole document rightwards unnecessarily. The contents of those tags should always be indented for clean markup, so that the nesting structure is clear to the reader.

To answer your question explicitly:

> Should `<head>` and `<body>` tags be on a different level of indentation to `<html>`?

There is no need for that, as everybody knows they are nested in `<html>`. You can do it if you want. Both

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>…</title>
        …
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>…</div>
            …
        </div>
        …
    </body>
<html>
```

and

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>…</title>
    …
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>…</div>
        …
    </div>
    …
</body>
<html>
```

are fine, while the following is not:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>…</title>
…
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>…</div> <!-- which nesting level ??? -->
…
</div>
…
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Whilst the language is not indentation sensitive such as python,  indentation certainly improves the readability, and I was simply wondering if there was a set standard. " Whilst I appreciate that it probably doesn't make the slightest bit of difference as far as the functionality of the final website goes "

Comment: I am not aware of any coding standards for html markup.

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to HTML mom.

Comment: Still, it makes sense to indent any subnodes. So I wonder where the "let's not indent head and body" originates from, because I see it *everywhere*

Comment: @nl-x Exactly. Which is why I tried to find a middle-ground in my answer below. Judging by the votes, quite unpopular. I honestly find it surprising.

Comment: Though it hasn't changed for many years, I believe that indenting future-proofs your code, should the W3C decide to bring in more child nodes for the HTML tag. I'm not adverse to reading unindented nodes under HTML, so long as everything else is indented beneath **head** and **body**.

Answer (score 11):

It does not matter in functionality, but for the purpose of **clean**, **readable** and **manageable** code you should always indent child tags.

Answer (score 1):

I teach an introductory course in web design and have quite a challenge to explain to students why indentation is important especially for someone new to HTML. I often show them the DOM diagram from [the W3schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as an example of the tree structure which is an HTML page. In my honest opinion, although knowing full well that it does not make a difference in the slightest, indenting both the `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` helps to show the HTML tree structure better. As someone above said, indentation makes for clear readable code but not just, `<head>` and `<body>` are both children of `<html>` and thus should be indented to show this fact.

Comment: People say: "It does not make a difference", but it does. Readability is one of the most important factors in this debate. I agree tht sub tags should *always* be indented. I'm the same with any code, the only exception being SQL, which can be a bit of a localised nightmare depending on your organisation.

Answer (score -6):

Multiple people suggested the following:

> you should always indent child tags.

I disagree and think this is too puristic. Nobody would reject the following because not every child tag is indented:

```html
<h2><i class="fa fa-icon"></i> Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

So, trying to find a middle ground, I propose a more moderate view. Instead of this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>That's 2 levels of indenting and we haven't even started yet.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or this (nobody knows why people started doing this):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to propose another style. A three-line general structure:

```html
<html><head> <!-- Start -->
    <style>
    </style>
</head><body> <!-- Separator between head and body -->
    <div>
    </div>
</body></html> <!-- End -->
```

In this case, we get rid of an indentation level in a natural way (because a double indentation wouldn't make sense). It's the `head` and `body` elements that cause indentation of its content.

Comment: Awful! Simply awful.

Comment: @Paul What is awful about it? Nobody could explain why it's so bad up until this point. Maybe you can enlighten me.

Comment: The readability is really poor. By putting things on the same line like that it makes it far less readable. It's more confusing than anything else. I tried it once, myself, but instantly reverted to indented body and head.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand that. We're talking about 6 tags. 4 of which are at the very start and very end of the document. So really only the middle 2 are relevant. And if you don't forget to indent any of the descendants, it's immediately clear where the "gutter" between HTML `head` and `body` is. Whether that gutter is 1 line or 2 lines really doesn't matter one bit.

Comment: Well, if you want to use it like that, fill your boots. Personally I think it's ugly. What happens if W3C introduces more tags to include under HTML? Are you going to stack them as well? I've seen a few similar ugly nestings, such as opening paragraph tags on a line by themselves then the closing tag on the end of the text *<shudders>*. I am surprised that this post wasn't closed IMHO, due to it being a matter of preference. The key is to work as your organisation works. If you are your own organisation, then fair enough. If not, then you should toe the line.

Comment: `What happens if W3C introduces more tags to include under HTML?` That is purely hypothetical. `similar ugly nestings, such as opening paragraph tags on a line by themselves then the closing tag on the end of the text` That is not similar at all. My suggestion is similar to `<tr><td>[newline]blabla[newline]</td><td>[newline]foo[newline]</td></tr>`, which is proper indenting, even if it's not to your tastes.

Comment: You asked me what I thought. Either accept that I think this is not a good method (as per the other people who have marked your post down) and the reasons I've given, or don't. I'd never use your method for doing this as I don't find it as readable. (I would also ask any of my team not to use this method if they started doing it). Completely up to you.

Comment: And me having a hard time comprehending your purist opinion and arguing against it is entirely up to me. By the way, my answer also has upvotes.